# Too many options in the View Data Class select list when creating a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Is there a way to restrict the options available in the view data class select list in the MVC add view dialog box.  I really would only like to have models from a single assembly in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the ViewData class and type it in manually after the view is created. I find that faster than scrolling through that awefull list.

Answer (score 1):

When you start typing the list filters itself so that you can find the type more easily.